# Domain name not found by PHP network functions like checkdnsrr

Tags: php, dns, mx-record

I have a PHP function which checks whether an Email address is valid. As part of this, it looks to see if the domain exists:

```
if(!(checkdnsrr($domain, "MX") || checkdnsrr($domain, "A"))) {
    throw new Exception("Bad domain name $domain");
}
```

This has worked fine for just about everything, except a domain that I've just come across: monsignor-reggio.com.

According to checkdnsrr() or any of the other PHP network functions such as gethostbynamel(), it doesn't exist. (By the way, according to ping or traceroute from the OS X command line, it doesn't exist either). But it's definitely a domain which is capable of sending and receiving email.

Help!

Comment: It might be a coincidence, but it had [its anniversary on the 14th and was updated (possibly renewed) on the 15th](http://whois.domaintools.com/monsignor-reggio.com). It *might* be waiting for the renewal to propogate.

Comment: Actually, whois reports "Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2015-12-14T12:43:47Z", so the domain has expired, so it is no longer a valid domain - your code is correct.